# Subscription with shipping class cost 0 still showing regular price

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have some variable subscription created using Woocommerce Subscription, and they share a shipping class

```
(Called "Subscription Shipping", id:"subscription_shipping")
```

that has **0** cost for the flat rate used.

The cost for the flat rate and for no-shipping class is **9.95**.

If I verify the shipping class using

```
$cart_item[data] -> get_shipping_class()
```

I get a correct id: "subscription_shipping".

Still, on my checkout I get the **9.95** cost for shipping.

Any ideas on how to set this up so I get **0** cost for the variable subscriptions using that shipping class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found!
The general cost has to be 0. (this is where I was doing wrong)
The shipping class tax has to also be 0.
But the no-shipping class has to be the regular tax, in my case: 9.95.